# What ist the standart root idirecton in a webapplication using SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, web-applications, view, sapui5

I'm new in SAPUI5 and javascript and I'm working on a web application using SAPUI5. For this, I have several views located in ./logonapp/CustomerList.view.js and controllers located also in ./logonapp/CustomerList.controller.js. The folder "logonapp" and also my "index.html" file are in the "wwww" folder in my application.
Now I have to say to SAPUI5 where my view and controller are located. So I'm using `sap.ui.localResources("???");` but wich direction should be in the brakes? 
I found different versions, for example: [Registering Component Resources](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/9c/5a9619f69f4a819f91fc89d9ff56f1/content.htm?frameset=/en/30/1b05f212334a66b1a2bc5411a6c030/frameset.htm) but it I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sap.ui.localResources("logonapp"); for registering resources. For this to work the folder 'logonapp' should be in the same directory as index.html.

You can call your view this way then

```
var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"customerList"});
var page = sap.ui.view({id:"customerList", viewName:"logonapp.CustomerList", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
app.addPage(page);
```

Comment: thats the right answer. Thank you, with it it works. I want to give you a positive feedback, but it isn't allowed for me, sorry for that

Comment: If my answer solves your problem then please mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way to do this is in the bootstrap:

```
<script
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-preload="async"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.ui.demo.wt": "./"
    }' >
```

The data-sap-ui-resourceroots setting is what you are looking for. For more information see the [UI5 Walkthrough Tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1409791afe4747319a3b23a1e2fc7064.html) from the SAPUI5 team. There you will also learn the best practices for you project's folder structure. Maybe you also want to check the [Navigation and Routing Tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d.html), since I guess you are using multiple views...

Comment: I know this tutorial, but as you can see data-sap-ui-resourceroots= ./ so thats the root of my index.html file, but in this way I can't say were my other resources are

Comment: Yes, you can:

data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.ui.demo.wt": "./",
        "logonapp" : "./logonapp/"
}'

That should work just fine. However, using sap.ui.localResources() works as well. It might be even better to set the resource roots in the app descriptor, see https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html (search for "resourceRoots").